Python code pauses execution randomly till I move the VS Code Terminal
I am running an code which performs inference for several hours. However when it seems to randomly pause.
But when I move the VS Code's terminal border/window slightly, it starts executing. I don't seem to understand the correlation. what is the reason for this, and how to fix this. Is it a VS Code issue?

Is your computer in power saving mode (e.g. Windows "Power saver" plan, or "Energy Saver" enabled, or similar)? IIRC, Windows might freeze a terminal in such situation if it doesn't have the focus, and as a result, your application might freeze when it tries to write to the terminal because the buffer is full.

No, the settings are changed for best Performance, all Energy Saving settings are disabled.

You could try running it from the normal PowerShell terminal, instead of the terminal integrated in VS Code, that would at least narrow down if it is VS Code terminal integration or the PowerShell terminal itself.

Running via Powershell seems to work without any interrupts. Seems to be the fix, will get back incase any issue comes up.
